# Converting 3-class predictions to single score

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, ordinal-data, sentiment-analysis

I have model predictions for 3 ordinal classes, negative, neutral and positive for the sentiment of a given text. For further analysis I'd like to have only a single number to specify the sentiment of this text.

Would it be reasonable to calculate the sentiment score of a text as `(-1 * P(neg)) + (0 * P(neut)) + (1 * P(pos))`? If so, do you have any citations you can refer to?

Comment: Transforming an ordinal dependent variable into a continuous variable is not ideal because you will be assuming that the distance between classes are the same (i.e. neutral-negative = positive-neutral). Running a multi-class classification model on the three categories is also not ideal because then you would lost the ordinal information. Running an ordinal regression might be the best option.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to make that kind of assumption in an ordinal regression? Is that assumption the only issue?

Comment: Ordinal regression makes no assumption about the distance between classes, but merely their relative ordering. I'm not sure how this applies to calculating a sentiment score though. I think it is much more complicated than a trivial transformation of the classes.

Comment: And you can get a single score out of ordinal regression that's between the 3 classes such as 0.5? Hmm.. it seems to me that the ordinal regression model needs to have some kind of assumption about the distance between the classes. Otherwise, it seems too unconstrained with the vast number of possible distances between the classes. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

[Micro and Macro-Averaging](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/multiclass-metric.html) have been proposed for this.